# colsplit not keeping all columns in dataframe

Tags: r

I have taken a column and split it into two using `colsplit`. My dataframe is made up of the two columns from the split. I lost all the other columns in the dataframe. How do I split the one column and add the new split columns to the current dataframe?

Dataframe before split

```
              X0      X1 Period
           <chr>   <dbl>  <int>
1 1973 January   108.289      1
2 1973 February   97.698      2
3 1973 March      97.366      3
4 1973 April      93.084      4
5 1973 May        94.346      5
6 1973 June       97.757      6
```

Applying `colsplit`

```
> A <- colsplit(subemission$X0, " ", c("Year", "Month"))
> head(A)
  Year     Month
1 1973 January  
2 1973 February 
3 1973 March    
4 1973 April    
5 1973 May      
6 1973 June
```

Comment: `colsplit` is not a function in base R. Please include the names of packages that your are using in your question.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr` with `remove=FALSE`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate(subemission, XO, into = c("Year", "Month"), remove = FALSE)
```

---

Or with `cSplit`

```
cSplit(subemission, "XO", " ", drop = FALSE)
```

---

Or a `base R` option with `read.table`

```
cbind(subemission, read.table(text= subemission$XO, 
   header=FALSE, col.names = c("Year", "Month"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```